# Jquery Datatables same result

Tags: php, jquery

Using Server side processing, with Ignited Datatables, getting the same result set no mater the action I take no other errors are returned.

The page example: I haven't given the server a name can't include link..

```
> http://104.200.17.5/BotController
```

### JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable( {
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": 'BotController/IpTest',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart ":20,
                "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"
        },  
        "fnInitComplete": function() {
                //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
         },
                'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
            {
                    //  console.log(fnCallback);
              $.ajax
              ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'     : sSource,
                'data'    : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback
              });
            }
 } ); 
});
```

### The server call:

```
public function IpTest()
{

           //ob_clean();
            $this->datatables->select('ID,Voting_ID,User_IP,X_IP')
                 ->unset_column('ID')
                 ->from('User_IP_check');



    echo $this->datatables->generate(); 

}
```

Comment: Was this on purpose?:

    "sProcessing": "assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"


I ask because you have a string with an end to a single quote in there, that just seems weird, unless its is being concatenated to another half that ends with a single quote too

Comment: When you say "getting the same result set" what do you mean? The query is returning the same data, or $this->datatables->generate() is giving you the same set?

Comment: Also what framework are you using? Not sure what unset_column() does.

Comment: $this->datatables->generate() is returning to me the same result set. Post data is being sent. Unset_column is a ignited datatable method it simply removes the ID column from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use this, and bind all your column names into mData.

```
 "aoColumns": [{
         "mData": "col_name_1"
     }, {
         "mData": "col_name_2"
     }, {
         "mData": "col_name_3"
     }, {
         "mData": "col_name_3"
     }

     ],
```